# R library(qdap) installation error

Tags: r, devtools, qdap

I am having difficulty installing the qdap library, see below:

I installed the Java library first, and then the qdap library:
        Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7')
        library(rJava)

## then the devtools library:

```
    library(devtools)
    install_github("trinker/qdapDictionaries")
    install_github("trinker/qdapRegex")
    install_github("trinker/qdapTools")
    install_github("trinker/qdap")
```

The other installations before qdap go fine, but at qdap this error is generated:

> install_github("trinker/qdap")
>   Downloading github repo trinker/qdap@master
>   Installing qdap
>   Skipping 3 packages ahead of CRAN: qdapDictionaries, qdapRegex, qdapTools
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
>     CMD INSTALL  \
>     "C:/Users/Seema/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMdVHCQ/devtools101432a84788/trinker-qdap-85cbe87"  \
>     --library="C:/Users/Seema/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests

- installing *source* package 'qdap' ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** tests
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error occurred during initialization of VM
  Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
  Error: Command failed (1)

What dependent libraries is it looking for? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146968/cannot-install-proprietary-r-library Does `require("rJava") ` work?